# SESSION from a page to another not working

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a PHP website, the session is not working after updated to 5.3
the session get expire when moved to another page.

I have tried the following but nothing worked out

1. changed session path session.save_path
2. changed cookie path "session.cookie_path"
3. deleted all the existing sessions
4. changed the session folder permission to 777
5. added session_start() on top of all the pages.

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: can you share you code ?

Comment: sorry i cant share the coed as per the company policy

Comment: sorry I will be unable to help you.

Comment: flow is- once the user get authenticated then we are setting flag $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;,  then  redirecting to another page . there the $_SESSION['logged_in'] is empty.

Answer (score 0):

***While you are not sharing any code to understand the issue ->***

simple and for starters.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 //after checking the login credentials

 $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
 if($_SESSION['logged_in'] = true){
  header('Location: /directory/home.php'); 
 }else{
 echo "You must login";
 }
```

in other page /directory/home.php -> here first check if the session is set to start

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}

if($_SESSION['logged_in'] = true){
  echo "You are Login";
 }else{
 echo "You must login";
}
```